# Shorted the psu and computer won't post with new one

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, troubleshooting

I accidentally shorted my PSU on a damaged SATA power connector. I picked up a replacement [Thermaltake 700](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/thermaltake-smart-700w-atx-80-plus-power-supply-black/6339087.p?skuId=6339087) PSU and dropped it in.

Now the PC won't POST. I unplugged everything except the VGA/HDMI (Tried both) and it powers on (with the CPU fan spinning), but nothing appears on screen.

Then I remembered the 4-pin ATX connector was unplugged so I connected that, but it won't even power on (no CPU fan spinning) with that connected. Without the connected 4-pin ATX power, it would at least power on (CPU fan spins). Any ideas?

Here's my parts:

[ASUS PRIM H310](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-H310-PLUS/)

[Thermaltake 700](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/thermaltake-smart-700w-atx-80-plus-power-supply-black/6339087.p?skuId=6339087)

Intel coffee lake CPU

Comment: Maybe you damaged the motherboard as well as the PSU.

Comment: To electronics shorting VCC to Ground is one of those issues that can do all sorts of damage.  Just because the CPU fan was spinning, does not mean the CPU is functional, nearly everything is directly connected to the CPU in some capacity.  I suspect the short did massive damage.

Comment: Frying a motherboard with a short anywhere in the system can happen. The only thing left is to reset the CMOS/Firmware settings: Unplug the power cord, see page 1-1 of your motherboard manual https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/PRIME_H310-PLUS/E13818_PRIME_H310-PLUS_UM_WEB.pdf to remove the coin battery. Let it sit for 5 minutes by the clock, put the coin battery back in, plug in and retry getting into POST and BIOS/Firmware to reset to factory default settings.